# algorithm for finding all substrings from a specific alphabet in a string in O(m+n) time

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching

Given a string S . Find all maximal substrings that contains chars from alphabet A in O(|S|+|A|) time. "Maixmal susbstring" is a substring of S, surrounded by chars that are not in alphabet A, or string boundaries.

example:

```
S = rerwmkwerewkekbvverqwewevbvrewqwmkwe

A = {w,r,e}
```

answer: `rerw, werew, e, er, wewe, rew, w, we`

Can you help?

Comment: There are vastly more than O(m+n) substrings of such a string, so this is impossible.  Also what have you thought of so far?

Comment: What is the answer for your specific example?

Comment: Hint: create a data structure such that you can answer the query "is element of A" in constant time O(1).

Comment: edited, that's the desired output

Comment: @user3704360: double check the desired output, I see two errors

Comment: @j_random_hacker The question specifies maximum substrings, so that makes it possible.

Comment: @Dan: You're right, it does -- *now*.  The OP hasn't yet updated the title, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping your input to the output that you've provided here is one way to do it.

1. Just take the string characters one at a time and keep matching it to the alphabets in A.
2. Use a binary hash-table having 26 values based on alphabet.
   Note: If capitals are included too hash them to their small letter counterparts for case-insensitivity and and double the hash table size for case-sensitivity.
3. If a value matches move on and concatenate this to previous sub-string.
4. If there is a miss, then break the sub-string, save it and start fresh with the next match.

Without the hash-table it would take O(m*n) time but now it'll take O(m) for hashing plus O(n) for traversing that is O(m+n) time.

Comment: You can also use a 26 element array instead of a fancier hash table (because it basically is a simple hash table).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what others have suggested, but in pseudocode form:

```
A = boolean array

for each c in the alphabet
    set A[c] = true 

L = stack of strings containing your solution

for each character c of S
    if A contains c
        append c to the top string of stack L
    else
        push empty string onto stack L

return L
```

Creating `A` will take `O(n)` and iteration through S will take `O(m)`.

Comment: Actually, hash value of chars doesn't make sense. ASCII code is enough to identify it. int contains[256]. contains['a'] = 1, for example. But the algorithm is ok. It's also possible to send the results to output without pushin to stack (because pushing to stack is O(1) just in just amortized estimation)

Comment: Yes, you're right. An integer or boolean should be used instead since a char can be hashed by just an integer cast. I updated my answer.